# Processing Spcial Chars while loading csv in dataweave

Tags: dataweave

I've below data in data.csv containing backslash

special chars before doublequotes

[image]

For the following transformation

```
output application/csv quoteValues=true
```

Getting a weird output and and the size of payload is 3 instead of 4.
[image]

What am I missing here ?

Note when I load this csv in pandas, all the four rows are loaded

Comment: The easier way to help you is to either provide the file through a link or copy-n-paste the contents with the backslashes intact.

Comment: Add the screenshot for 4 rows 2 columns with special chars

Comment: You should not use screenshots for text information in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  likely that that line 3 misses and end quote.  The backslash character is the default escape character. The last quote is then part tof the  field. To add a single backlash you need to escape it with another backslash `\\`.

Comment: Are we going to ask the data provider to add this?  But pandas automatically loads this without any problem. Why dataweave puts a constraint like this?

Comment: DataWeave uses a different CSV parser than pandas. It may be more strict than pandas's. Note that the CSV is not very well formed. CSV is not a very well defined format from the start. It would be better to use a formally defined format like XML. Even JSON is better defined than CSV.

Comment: The CSV is invalid as far as I am concerned.

Comment: It would require a new feature to support this kind of invalid file. For example a flag to finish the field at end of line, as if it were correctly quoted. But that could allow invalid files to be treated as valid.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. We can not change the file type it will stay as csv. Do we need to enforce the provider of the data include additional escape chars?

Comment: either the provider ensures that the file has a valid CSV format or you will need to do some custom code to fix the invalid lines.